# Search table names that has 3 exact columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

What's wrong with the below script? I am trying to locate all the tables that has the following column names: ItemID, QueryID, and CurrencyID. Currently, it only gives me tables that has 2 columns out the 3 mentioned so one of the column will be missing.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME in ('ItemID', 'QueryID', 'CurrencyID')
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want all 3 to match as well as 2, why don't you use

```
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: Won't it have to be `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3` or even `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3` ?  Setting it to `>= 2` will still return the tables that only have two of the three.  **Edit:** just saw your edit

Comment: @Tom:  I have no idea what the OP wants.   I am trying to point in the correct direction.

Comment: This is did not work. I need all the tables that contains the mentioned three column names. I found a work around using QlikView software for now.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.name 
FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
ON t.object_id = c.object_id 
WHERE c.name IN ('ItemID', 'QueryID', 'CurrencyID')
GROUP BY t.name 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.name) >= 3
```

Comment: Third party database won't let me use sys.tables. Thanks though. I found a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate answer to avoid `>` / `=` / `>=` issues:

This will only return a table when all 3 are found, but wallyk's answer is spot on given your question... choose his if it works for you.

```
SELECT T.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1 WHERE T.TABLE_NAME=C1.TABLE_NAME AND C1.COLUMN_NAME='ItemID')
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C2 WHERE T.TABLE_NAME=C2.TABLE_NAME AND C2.COLUMN_NAME='QueryID')
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C3 WHERE T.TABLE_NAME=C3.TABLE_NAME AND C3.COLUMN_NAME='CurrencyID')
```